# PBI Data parameters

Tags: parameters, filter, powerbi

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically filter the data I import into PowerBI (desktop or online), so I can share dashboards with specific clients but only use the data relevant to that client.

Thanks

Comment: If your datasource is an Analysis Services server the data will be filtered based on the permissions you set to the account.

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this by editing a Query which lists Clients to Filter for the selected client. Then I would add Merge steps (setting Join Kind = Inner) to all the relevant Queries to restrict them to just the rows matching that filtered Clients Query.

Once that is working, then using PBI Desktop you can go back to Edit Queries and edit that Filter (e.g. choose a different Client), then Refresh the Report data.

I built a working solution (using Northwind Customers in place of Clients) which you can download from my OneDrive and try out:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: **Power BI Demo - Dynamically filter data.pbix**

Comment: You just need to be careful if you use that solution that the user isn't able to access the original data source.  They might open the PBIX file and change your filter values :).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to put your data in Analysis Services Tabular server you host and set some security rules for data access so that different users see different data.  Then build a report in the Power BI service that connects to the AS server, the queries will execute in the context of the user accessing your report and AS will filter the results automatically. The solution you ultimately choose will depend on the nature of your interaction with your customers.